# Podcast application for Linux allowing control of the audio speed

Tags: linux, podcast

I am looking for a podcast application for Linux with one feature: I want to be able to speed up or slow down the audio as I wish (as it is possible for instance in [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivoox.app&hl=es) Android app).

Any other feature is pretty much irrelevant to me.